# RangeError: Invalid time value with toDisplayDate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting the error RangeError: Invalid time value when I use toDisplayDate, anyone know why I am encountering this?

```
import React from "react";
import toDisplayDate from "date-fns/format";

  this.state = {
     userGifts: [],
     userSinceDate: toDisplayDate(
        this.props.currentUser.createdAt,
        "MMMM do, y"
     ),
     // currentUser: {},
  };
```

}

Comment: What's the value of this.props.currentUser.createdAt, is it a valid Date?

Comment: I used the Date.now() function to grab a user's date.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, I am using global state to check my user in. When I refresh the page, the user is logged out which is causing that error to show.